# Is $x\ln|x|$ analytic at $x=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My task is to find the singular points and classify them as regular or irregular for the following ODE:

$$ y'' + (\ln|x|)y' + 3xy = 0 $$

Clearly, the only singular point is at $x=0$ where the logarithm blows up. Now, I am having difficulty judging its regularity. By definition, according to my text, the singular point is regular if:

$$ x\ln|x| $$ is analytic at $x=0$. If we take the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow0}x\ln|x| = 0 $$ we see that the singular point is a removable discontinuity of $x\ln|x|$which I think implies that the singular point is regular. My textbook answers, however, show this be an irregular singular point. What is the correct approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be analytic at $x=0$, the function and all of its derivatives must exist in a neighborhood of $x=0$.  However, if $f(x)=x\log(|x|)$ and $f(0)=0$, we see that $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\log(|h||)}{h}$ fails to exist.  Therefore, $f$ is not analytic at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The consequence of this then is that we can't write a Taylor Series expansion about our singular point for $x\ln|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = x\ln|x|$ is analytic at $x = 0$, you can differentiate it there.  What's $f'(0)$?

> $f'(0)$ is undefined.  $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f'(x) = -\infty$.

So is it analytic at $x = 0$?

Comment: It might be confusing that you have $f'(0)$ does not exist and then continue by writing $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=-\infty$.  Both are true, but it just might mislead some readers that you are equating the two.

Comment: @MarkViola : I write $f'(0)$ is undefined.  $0$ is not in the domain of $f'$, so $f'$ is not defined there.  What would be confusing is using "does not exist", a property/outcome of limits.

Comment: The limit quotient fails to exist.  Hence the derivative fails to exist.  $0$ is in the domain of $f$ and one needs to test to see whether $f'(0)$ exist.  Yo

Comment: @MarkViola : If this were a Calculus class, I would argue as you are.  This is a differential equations class.  In this setting, we should treat $f'$ as a first-class object.  That function exists and has a domain.  That domain does not include $0$.  Therefore, $f'$ is not defined at $x = 0$.